# Hahn-Banach Theorems

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, exponential-function, hahn-banach-theorem

Theorem: Let $X$ be a normed space and let $x_0\neq 0$ be any element of $X$. Then there exists a bounded linear functional $f^\sim$ on $X$ such that $||f^\sim||=1$, $f^\sim(x_0)=||x_0||$.

NOTE: I know the proof of this theorem.

Show that under the assumptions of Theorem there is a bounded linear functional $f^\wedge$ on $X$ such that $||f^\wedge||=||x_0||^{-1}$ and $f^\wedge(x_0)=1$.

Comment: Why not let $\hat f = \dfrac{\tilde f}{||x_0||}$?

Comment: yes, this equation applies. but how can I prove this? I thought of starting the proof by defining a functional and subspace. @Zerox

Comment: My construction derives directly from the theorem you state. Since you know the proof of the theorem you can construct $\hat f$ similarily.

Comment: Thank you @Zerox